# 'new auto' in C++ constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, member, auto

Can C++ somehow accept this use of 'auto'?:

```
class A {
    public:
        A(): m_member(new auto)
        {
                [...]
        }

    private:
        BoringToTypeType *m_member;
}
```

The purpose is to take advantage of 'auto' by simplifying the member element initialisation in A's constructor. As it is, the code raises the following error:

```
new expression for type 'auto' requires a constructor argument.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new auto(...)` deduces the type of the resultant pointer from the expression passed inside `(...)`. In your particular case there's nothing that can be deduced.

You have a few options:

- `m_member(new auto(x))`, where `x` is an expression of type `BoringToTypeType`.
- `m_member(new std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(m_member)>)`, which is most certainly not an improvement over `BoringToTypeType`.

If you don't mind defining an additional helper function, here's an alternative solution:

```
template <typename T, typename... TArgs>
auto newer(T*, TArgs&&... args)
{
    return new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
} 

class A 
{
    public:
        A(): m_member(newer(m_member, 12))
        {

        }

    private:
        int *m_member;
};
```

In this case `T` is used purely for type deduction purposes. `m_member` has to be repeated twice, but you avoid typing out its type this way.

[Simple tests on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/IzGtAm) show that `newer` does not incur any additional overhead.

Comment: The second form I would consider as idiomatic in C++, as `pvar = malloc(sizeof *pvar);` is in C. Just a tangent thought. **+1**.

Comment: @StoryTeller: unfortunately I pressed "answer" too soon, as `decltype(m_member)` evaluates to a pointer type... The pointer has to be removed somehow.

Comment: What about `decltype(*m_member)`. Any chance for salvation there? Or will the cursed `decltype` deduction rules evaluate it to a reference? Regardless an excellent answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller: as you guessed, it will evaluate to a reference. Therefore something like `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*m_member)>`has to be used. Quite sad - I'm experimenting to find a better alternative

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to repeat that type name, you can add a private alias:

```
class A {
    using mem_t = BoringToTypeType;
    public:
        A(): m_member(new mem_t)
        {
                [...]
        }

    private:
        mem_t *m_member;
}
```

Of course, in real code you should use `std::unique_ptr` or similar instead of raw pointers in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You might define auto constructor class - the idea it to have new object created when casting needed to pointer to this object ([working demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Z3flUKrZqpeCvLSW)):

First this auto-constructor (or maybe any-constructor) class:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename ...T>
class AutoConstructor
{
public:
    template <typename ...U>
    AutoConstructor(U&&... a) : params(std::forward<U>(a)...) {}

    template <typename U>
    operator U* ()
    {
        return construct<U>(std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
    }
private:
    template <typename U, std::size_t ...I>
    U* construct(std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        return new U(std::forward<T>(std::get<I>(params))...);
    }
    std::tuple<T...> params;
};
```

It would be hard to use this class w/o helper make function:

```
template <typename ...T>
auto makeAuto(T&&... a)
{
   return AutoConstructor<T...>(std::forward<T>(a)...);
}
```

Then - such "magic" is possible:

```
long&& d = 7;
int* a = makeAuto();
S *s = makeAuto(std::ref(*a), 2, std::make_unique<float>(3), std::move(d));
```

Assuming S has c-tor `S(int& a, const int& b, std::unique_ptr<float> c, long d)`

Just to summarize - this piece of code I presented is quite easy to use - but I doubt it would be good habit to have everywhere in the code `makeAuto` calls...

Answer (score -1):

Make m_member a `std::unique_ptr`, and you will get access to `element_type`.  So the code looks like:

```
class A {
    public:
        A(): m_member(std::make_unique<decltype(m_member)::element_type>(...))
        {
                [...]
        }

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<BoringToTypeType> m_member;
};
```

It's debatable whether that's an improvement - but it helps if `BoringToTypeType` is more complex.